# Excluding one item from list and take all others while traversing the list

Tags: c#, optimization

This is the problematic line:

```
var sbData = Items[i].GetSubitemsInRangeData(Items.Where(item => item.Id != Items[i].Id).ToArray());
```

In need to traverse the list, call a method on every item in the list, except the current item, then some sub items will do something to a random item (of course, except the current item).

I want to optimize the above mentioned line by avoiding the creation of Items.Count lists all over again because I call DoStuff() very often.

I could not find anything related to my situation so I'm hoping somebody will answer or at least mark it as a duplicate and point me in the right direction.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static List<IItem> Items = new List<Items>();

    public static void Main()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            AddAndRemoveToItems();
            DoStuff();
        }   
    }

    public static void DoStuff()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var sbData = Items[i].GetSubitemsInRangeData(Items.Where(item => item.Id != Items[i].Id).ToArray());

            for (var j = 0; j < sbData.Count; j++)
            {
                DoSomethingWith(sbData[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SubItem : ISubItem
{
    public bool InRange(IItem item) { /* some logic here*/ };
    public bool SomeCondition() { /* some logic here*/ };
    public void DoSomethingTo(IItem item) { /* some logic here*/ };
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    public List<ISubItem> SubItems = new List<ISubItem>();

    public List<DataType> GetSubitemsInRangeData(List<ItemType> items)
    {
        var sbData = new List<Data>();

        foreach (var subItem in SubItems.Where(sb => sb.SomeCondition()))
        {
            var itemsInRange = items.Where(item => subItem.InRange(item)).ToList();

            if (itemsInRange.Length == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var targetItem = itemsInRange.Shuffle()[0]; // pick a random item from the list

            subItem.DoSomethingTo(targetItem);

            sbData.Add(new Data
            {
                TargetId = targetItem.Id,
                Index = subItem.Index
            });
        }

        return sbData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create once(all items) then use it always? Add an "if" in the subitems computing so it doesn't use "i" when it is equal to current selected item.

Comment: Items is initialized once and I add and remove items from it between DoStuff() calls. GetSubitemsInRangeData needs Items except Items[i]

Comment: foreach (var subItem in SubItems.Where(sb => sb.SomeCondition() && i!=j))

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've amended the original post to make sure everybody understands who is a member of who. Does your solution still apply?

Comment: If I understand right, this could be something like bouncing cars whose don't bounce with themselves?

Comment: Yes, great analogy. I know I can get away with an if statement, but that will run on every element, although I know on what element I don't want to run it on.
Seems like I'm chasing my own tail and another pair of eyes might have an elegant solution (if it even exists).

Comment: If you need to "software cache" each sub-list(which excludes every item's itself), it would need O(N*N) memory. If there are millions of items, adding a simple if would be faster for desktop computers because more items would fit in "hardware cache". Also you could move whole function's ingredients into getSubItemsInRangeData and check the "if" in there so calculation would be in-place without any extra array operation. But this would make its name calcSubItemsInRangeData then. Also just an "if" is nothing if items are somewhat not random and close to nothing when there are heavy calculations.

Comment: In this case I will merge the logic in one place and just use the "if". Thought of sub-lists myself but I think the cost of updating all the lists is bigger then the gain of using them. Thank you.